# Stormpath - Create User Terms and Conditions Page

Tags: stormpath

Does stormpath provide an easy way to implement a terms and conditions page? I have not found much information regarding a way to go about doing this. I am using Express in NodeJS.

Any ideas help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should implement this as a page in your own application.  You can modify our default templates to includes links to your pages.